# PDF files not opening when coresponding link is visited

Tags: html, pdf, hyperlink, local-files

I have the following code, which displays the list of all PDF files, and when clicked, the corresponding file opens. This code worked correctly till the last week, but not now. I am unable to find the error.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Unit 3, ADS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> ADS unit 3- Binomial Queues</h1>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="G:\sravan\3-1\theory\ads\unit 3\pdf\intro.pdf" > Introduction </a> </li>
        <li><a href="G:\sravan\3-1\theory\ads\unit 3\pdf\61.pdf"> Binary Heaps </a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="G:\sravan\3-1\theory\ads\unit 3\pdf\611.pdf"  > Implementation of Insert and Delete min </a></li>
            <li><a href="G:\sravan\3-1\theory\ads\unit 3\pdf\612.pdf"  > Creating Heap. </a></li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="G:\sravan\3-1\theory\ads\unit 3\pdf\62.pdf"  > Binomial Queues </a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="G:\sravan\3-1\theory\ads\unit 3\pdf\621.pdf"  > Binomial Queue Operations </a></li>
            <li><a href="G:\sravan\3-1\theory\ads\unit 3\pdf\622.pdf"  > Binomial Amortized Analysis</a></li>
            <li><a href="G:\sravan\3-1\theory\ads\unit 3\pdf\623.pdf"  > Lazy BinomialQueues</a></li>
        </ul>

        <li><a href="G:\sravan\3-1\theory\ads\unit 3\pdf\64.pdf"  > Problems</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: In what browser does this happen? (Which version?) Where is this HTML page located?

Comment: Yea they do exist @Andy

Comment: It's happening in every browser. I've tried in Firefox, Flock, Safari. I am getting an error as follws:
The address wasn't understood
Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (g) isn't associated with any program
You might need to install other software to open this address.
The html page is located at G:\sravan\3-1\theory\ads\unit 3

Comment: Obviously this will only work on a device that has G drive mapped. Could it be a permissions issue? Can you open these paths on the same device using the file system? Also could you say what error you are getting, have a look in either firebug in Firefox or web developer in IE to see what errors are being returned.

Comment: What happens when you try to access the link? Page not displayed? Forbidden? White page?  Is G: a Mapped Network Drive - do you still have permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding file:/// in front of the links and changing all the \ to /

This will work for Internet Explorer, however Firefox and others will not allow this by default as it is a security risk and is not recommended.

[To Change security settings for Firefox to allow local links](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don%27t_work)